# Dynamic TableView with CollectionView in prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have dynamic TableView, with CollectionView in prototype cell. I created subclass of UITableViewCell and added Custom cell for TableView prototype cell. Also I added UICollectionVeiwCell as CustomCell for CollectionView.

How it's look like in Storyboard: 
[image]

Code below I'm using to create my scene:

```
//-=-=-=-==-=-=--==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-TableView methods-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 15;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       myCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (!cell) {
            cell = [[myCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
       return cell;
}

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-==


//-=-=-=-==-=-=--==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-CollectionView methods-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 7;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static   NSString* cellIdentifier = @"CVCell";
        CVCustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.cellTxtFld.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 1) { 
        cell.cellTxtFld.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.cellTxtFld.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 3) { 
        cell.cellTxtFld.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 4) {
        cell.cellTxtFld.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    }

    if (indexPath.row == 5) { 
        cell.cellTxtFld.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 6) { 
        cell.cellTxtFld.text =@"LAST";
    }

        return cell;
    }
```

How it's look like in simulator:

[image]

My question is, how can I have acces to each collectionView directly? For example I have 15 arrays, and I want that first collectionView (in first TableView's row) init by 0-index, second - 1 index and so on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can collectionView as a property in custom view class of Table view and work on it after. Pass the array from a method in custom cell for array of custom cell. Then you will be able to access collection view for each tableView directly.

Edit :More specific :

You have a tableView cell `myCustomCell`. Make a property of `UICollectionView` in it and you can set its delegate to controller only. Make a method in `myCustomCell`. that can be called in `cellForAtIndexpath` and set the delegate to self. Now,you can access your `UICollectionView` based on your need

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Your advice caused compilation failures. I made it by simple and stupid way - using counter in CellForItemForIndexPath. But I have no idea can I get textField.text for some TextField by my way. Can you help me?

Comment: You can set the tagging and then get it. You can chat with me @mrsamkitjain@gmail.com